# WARNING Control reaches end of non-void function c++

Tags: c++, warnings, return-type

I have following function in C++ code (Its just an example)

```
Object& XYZ::getObject(InObj obj) {
  try{ 
      return obj.getObj();
  }
  DC_THROW_ERROR(ExceptionObj, "Object Not Found");   // Macro which throws an exception
}
```

When I compile the above code I get Warning (ie control reaches end of non-void function)..The Macro gets expanded before compilation. So the compiler is aware that if its not returning something its throwing an exception. If so why does compiler gives warning??  These type of functions are evrywhere in my project. To get rid of these warnings i have written below line after the Macro.

```
return *(static_cast<Object*>(0));
```

Is it a correct way of fixing it?? I know its bit dodgy.. I can't change the code as for that i have to change around 1000 functions. So can anyone please tell me if there is any better way of fixing it??

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the definition of the macro?

Comment: OT: I'm wondering why you can return an `Object*` from a function which is declared to return an `Object&` ...

Comment: Do provide the definition of the macro as per Oli, and also what compiler you are using.

Comment: That macro would have to expand to catch(...) { throw jada; } to guarantee that there will never be an unassigned return value.  Hopefully it doesn't do something as horrible as that.

Comment: Check the preprocessor output. With gcc, use the -E flag.

Comment: @Martin: He is not returning an Object*. He is returning a reference, as advertised. In this case it is the NULL reference.

Comment: @David: What? There is no such thing as the NULL reference. Dereferencing NULL is UB. Also, he was indeed returning an Object* at the time Martin posted.

Comment: Why even bother having a throw in there if you're already in a try-catch? This is pretty disgusting code.

Comment: @Dead: Notice that there is no catch in the code. That macro *must* be expanding into a catch. (Which makes it even more disgusting.)

Comment: @Martinho: Yes, there is such a thing as a NULL reference. Creating one is undefined behavior, but every compiler I've worked on creates one using exactly the code used by the OP.

Comment: No, there isn't. References are aliases for objects. It's not "creating one" that produces undefined behavior. It's dereferencing the NULL *pointer*. You never "create one". There is no object to be aliased by a reference here.

Comment: Hi All ... Here the Macro get expanded to a template function which takes parameter as the exception object and then throws a generic exception  .. But there is no catch in that function.. It just formulates a generic exception object and calls throw...  as below  void throwErr(ExceptionObj& bj) { GenException e(....); throw e; }

Answer (score 3):

Listen to the compiler. Get rid of the (so far undisclosed) macro. Or just fix it, but better get rid of it  --  you're into the make-C++-look-like-language-X thing, which is ungood.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the code in the question is a faithful representation of the code that is causing the problem, the macro DC_THROW_ERROR must be something like

```
#define DC_THROW_ERROR(err) catch(...) {throw err;}
```

That semicolon after the `DC_THROW_ERROR("Object Not Found")` thus results in

```
Object& XYZ::getObject(InObj obj) {
  try { 
    return obj.getObj();
  }
  // This is the expansion of DC_THROW_ERROR("Object Not Found")
  catch (...) {
    throw ("Object Not Found");
  }

  ; // This is the semicolon that follows DC_THROW_ERROR("Object Not Found")
```

}

It is that extraneous semicolon, not the macro, that is getting the compiler in a tizzy about control reaching the end of a non-void function. That said, since statements in C and C++ are supposed to end with a semicolon, it is only natural that the human author of the code will add a semicolon after the end of the macro invocation.

Do you really need a macro here? Macros are evil in general. This macro is evil incarnate.

- It makes that try-catch block look like invalid syntax. Macros that make the code look invalid are doubly evil.
- It renames syntax. Doing `#define BEGIN {` is evil. Macros that rename syntax are doubly evil.
- It invites the programmer to add that semicolon at the end. Macros that should not be followed with a semicolon are doubly evil.
- That the macro invocation should not be followed with a semicolon apparently is not documented. Macros that do something evil but don't document the evilness are doubly evil.

All told, this macro is 2x2x2x2, or sixteen-fold evil. That makes this devil code.

Comment: Hi David.. Weird thing is the macro isn't catching any exception.. In turn its thorwing a generic exception which gets created from the passed specific exception object.. Not sure if thats correct.  These Macros are all over the place..So I can't change everything.. Just trying to fix the Warnings..

Comment: @user: Either that macro starts with `catch` or you have an invalid compiler. A `try` block must be followed by at least one `catch`. I ventured a guess regarding what the macro looks like assuming that you are using a compliant compiler. **Show the macro**. Oli asked you to do so right from the onset. Now I am asking you once again.